SpaceMouse doesn't work at all
I just got a SpaceMouse Pro Wireless and it doesn't do anything in Blender. (Works fine in other apps.) I read about a whole bunch of problems with button assignments, but for me basic movement doesn't work either at all. I tried with the wireless dongle, and through usb as well. Nothing.
Do I have to enable it in Blender or something? I see the NDOF section in Preferences but no on/off switch or alike.
Very recent Blender 4.1, +latest drivers. Halp pls?
Update:
It might be relevant that I have the SpaceMouse Wireless Pro Bluetooth Edition
I found this issue from a few months ago and I'm wondering if it is related:
https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/116535
https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/pulls/116393
I tried Blender 4.0 and 3.6. Doesn't work.
I tried older versions of the driver, that I could download: 10.8.9 and 10.6.something. It doesn't even matter, because apparently the driver doesn't even recognize this device before 10.8.20.
Update 2:
I tried it on another PC at works just fine. Same OS, same driver, same blender. (4.2 alpha didn't help the original machine either) I don't understand. Anyway, thank you all for your emotional support.

Don't know whether this helps?

And please let us know if you get it to work, I've been thinking about getting one!

@JohnEason it doesn't, but thank you. I think it's stuck even before that somehow. Like Blender not recognizing the device id or whatnot.
